# Write permission of php file in server

Tags: php, apache

I have created a php file which will open a text file(which resides in the same location along with the php file),and i also added some code thus i can change the content of the text file.It was working great in my local host but as soon as i upload the folder to a server i cant save the changed content to the file some permission related error is coming  up.Is there any way thus i can forcefully change the content of the file in server?I mean is there any way thus this permission related issues can be overcome?

Comment: Show the error and the code you are using.

Comment: okkk i giving just wait a bit..

Comment: chmod is your friend. Probably... otherwise check the include path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access it via FTP and change the permissions to 755 which allows everyone to read / execute and only yourself to write.

Read more about permissions to find what best suits your requirements.